# How to implement zooming feature with zxing barcode reading application?

Tags: android, zxing

I'm having the zxing barcode reading application. I need to add zooming feature in the application, so that i can scan barcode from larger distance.

i.e. during scanning the barcode, it should be able to zoom the camera preview.

How can i do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zooming doesn't really help, because it's digital zoom. In fact it tends to hurt scanning. It only helps by making the user hold back further, but you can do that with other UI prompts. But, it's not hard to set zoom. You set whatever zoom you want in `Camera.Parameters` in `CameraConfigurationManager`.