# How to implement zoom feature for Zxing Scanner?

Tags: android, qr-code

I have stucked in implementing zooming feature for ZxingScanner(QR code scanner).

I am using the following libraries.

```
implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9'
implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.5.0'
```

I have not used any java class. Only i wrote code like his.

```
private CaptureManager capture;
private DecoratedBarcodeView barcodeScannerView;

barcodeScannerView = findViewById(R.id.zxing_barcode_scanner);
barcodeScannerView.setTorchListener(this);

capture = new CaptureManager(this, barcodeScannerView);
capture.initializeFromIntent(getIntent(), savedInstanceState);
capture.decode();
```

By using only above code , i can scan any QR codes succesfully. Only zoom feature i am not able to add.

I have gone through the following links

[How to implement zooming feature with zxing barcode reading application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169398/how-to-implement-zooming-feature-with-zxing-barcode-reading-application)

[Zxing scanner Camera zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52556663/zxing-scanner-camera-zoom)  and some others. But did not get any solution.

Please help me with this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

according to the [EMBEDDING.md](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/master/EMBEDDING.md) ...this library has is no zoom feature.

the only option which would have an effect how the view would look alike:

> For a full-screen barcode scanner with no Toolbar, the recommended options are:

```
app:zxing_use_texture_view="false"
app:zxing_preview_scaling_strategy="centerCrop"
```

for proper zoom, this would need to be done with  [CameraConfigurationUtils](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/android-core/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/camera/CameraConfigurationUtils.java) ...

which that third party library (which is not `com.google.zxing`) does not consider.

Comment: i have gone through the CameraConfigurationUtils..i have added that code in in my project...but no idea how to make use in QRscanner activity...

Comment: @AngadiworldTechnologies unless you use that library, you would not even be able to, unless editing it's code... use `com.google.zxing` instead, in order to gain access to all it's features.